# Is there a relationship between graph entropy and node entropy?

Tags: graphs, entropy, weighted-graphs

Eagle, et al [1] discuss the notion of node entropy and this is captured in igraph via the diversity metric. I was wondering if there was any relationship between these node entropies and the idea of the entropy for the entire graph.

A related question: Does the concept of edge entropy make sense? The probability would be the ratio of the weight of the edge in question and the sum of the weights of all edges connected to the nodes incident to the edge in question.

[1]: N. Eagle, M. Macy, and R. Claxton, “Network Diversity and Economic Development,” Science, vol. 328, no. 5981, pp. 1029–1031, May 2010.

Comment: Would you care to include a definition of node entropy, graph entropy, and igraph in your question?  That would make it more self-contained.  Also, can you add a link to the text of the paper (a free copy, not behind a paywall), if one exists?  Finally, I don't understand the statement "The probability would be..." -- what probability?